# Making Single Page Web apps with parse.com crawlable

Tags: web-applications, parse-platform, search-engine, prerender

I'm building a web site with Parse.com, and trying to make it crawlable by FB and Google bots. The site is based on parse.com and doesn't use Angular.

I've looked into the thread [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055917/making-angularjs-and-parse-web-app-crawlable-with-prerender), and set up things accordingly on my end. I've created an endpoint to test the stuff:

```
app.get('/hello/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.render('hello');
});
```

Here is what I have in the log, when google bot fetches an url like

https://www.example.org/hello/#!a/b

```
I2015-11-10T05:35:18.580Z]v642 Ran custom endpoint with:
  Input: {"method":"GET","url":"/hello/","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","accept-encoding":"gzip,deflate","cache-control":"no-cache","from":"googlebot(at)googlebot.com","host":"www.example.org","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)","version":"HTTP/1.1","x-forwarded-for":"10.252.5.60","x-forwarded-proto":"https"}}
  Result: Success
```

Because Google crawler doesn't rewrite the Url using fragments, the wrong page snapshot is sent (corresponding to the base url+path without the parameters). Interestingly, facebookbot replaces the shebang with an escape fragment and fetch the url below:

```
/hello/?_escaped_fragment_=posts/abcdef
```

Which is correctly processed on parse's end, with pre-render.io sending the correct cached page.

I've been banging my head on this issue for hours now, Parse's folks are nowhere to be found for an issue that is somewhat fairly basic and important.

Has someone ever managed to make Parse's single page design work with Google and Facebook bots or is it simply a lost cause?

thanks!

PS: It seems that now, google bot tries to render AJAX pages, irrespective of escaped fragments. In other words, it seems that the default behaviour now, but at the same time, existing AJAX page *may* still be crawled with escaped fragments... see the thread [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/8YjIJj7Y_dw;context-place=topicsearchin/webmasters/ajax$20crawling) for feedback from web developers.

Comment: Important to note that Google's scrapers actually run scripts to resolve dynamic pages now: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html

Comment: True. But Google is neither explicit w/r to how they run it (ok, they say we follow 'render'), nor how deep they do it. And of course, as usual, 'it can be changed without notice'. It seems to work for most, but in my case, it doesn't at all.

Comment: Agreed, they definitely could be a bit more revealing in what the bots are willing to crunch. Also, did you see the "caveats" section on this page: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-seo-with-prerender-io?_escaped_fragment_=tag#caveats

Comment: Hey, thanks! I had the folks @ pre-render thru emails, we couldn't figure out what was wrong either. FB rewrites the urls with escaped fragments, works fine. But Google bots do try to run the JS engine, and it fails... I'm out of solutions now. It's so disappointing. I wouldn't be surprised to see that at the end of the day good will say 'use angularJS'.

Comment: quick question though. If I was to change the sitemap.xml, and replace all #! with ?_escaped_fragment_=, would google bot index my pages properly? (as in replace back to #! when displaying a search result ?

Comment: Wish I could help, but I couldn't say. It's true, Angular routing seems to work really well with Google's bots. Or React's isomorphic server side rendering, which works with all the bots. Pros & cons, I suppose...